# Powershell Release Manager Output

Tags: powershell, tfs, ms-release-management

I am working in a quite complex code base of powershell build scripts
with a lot of dependencies on other PS scripts. Everything is dot-sourced, no module.

As we are refactoring the code into functions, a lot of issues are creeping up, mainly a liberal use of write-output for logging.

I try to enforce using write-verbose for logging, because the scripts will be deployed in release manager.

For some reason, as a build is executing, I don't see the verbose information. It is only shown afterwards when I inspect a specific step.

Write-Verbose usually outputs "Verbose:...." but in release manager I get "##[debug]Verbose" instead.

Is there a way to hide the [debug]Verbose prefix? Is there a better way to output logging info that would be shown in release manager?

Comment: Hi BenoitM, any update on this issue?

Comment: I have been away for a while, but it looks like the output generated is not the same when it goes through release manager or if it is built directly with an agent from the tfs build definition. I will add more details when I get back.

Comment: Regarding the Verbose prefix, it was a bug in our code.

I have found that the Write-Host output is shown in the web portal release log with TFS 2017. This was not the case in release manager 2015. 

Now we can use Write-Host to output info to the users.

Answer (score 0):

This may due to you have [enable Verbose Output in Team Foundation Release Logs](http://blog.devmatter.com/enabling-verbose-output-in-team-foundation-build-logs/)

Navigate to the Variables tab and check if there is a variable named `system.debug` and its value set to true. If so, you will get a log  with ##[debug] prefix such as below screenshot:

[image]

Set the value= false or directly delete the variable.

Comment: I tried with system.debug = false, = true and deleting the variable and I still get the ##[debug] prefix. I also use $VerbosePreference = "Continue" in the scripts, maybe this is the cause?

Comment: @BenoitM What's the result if you change the continue to `$VerbosePreference="SilentlyContinue"` ?

Comment: As expected nothing is outputed using SilentlyContinue.

Comment: @BenoitM This is wired if you are using the some powershell script in build and release. One is  "Verbose:...." another is  "##[debug]Verbose" .  `Is there a better way to output logging info that would be shown in release manager ?` Another way is using [**logging commands**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). To invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Verbose prefix, it was a bug in our code. I have found that the Write-Host output is shown in the web portal release log with TFS 2017. This was not the case in release manager 2015. Now we can use Write-Host to output info to the users.

Comment: Did this also fix that output was first only shown after the complete script was run as described in your question?